# Call Jquery Function in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, function

I have one if-else and I want to call function which contain jquery script. but its not working

Here is my codeignitor view code

**Code**

```
if($osoption == "windows")
 {
    ?>
    <script>
        windows();
    </script>   
    <?
    $mysqldatabasehidden="N/A";
    if ($_POST['mssqldatabasehidden']=="")
    {
            $mssqldatabasehidden = "1 No";
    }
    else
    {
            $mssqldatabasehidden = $_POST['mssqldatabasehidden']." No";
    }
    if($_POST['mssqlstoragehidden']=="")
    {
        $mssqlstoragehidden = "100";
    }
    else
    {
        $mssqlstoragehidden = $_POST['mssqlstoragehidden']." MB";
    }
    if($_POST['mssqltotalcosthidden'] =="")
    {
        $mssqltotalcosthidden = "3000 INR";
    }
    else
    {
        $mssqltotalcosthidden = $_POST['mssqltotalcosthidden'].".00 INR";
    }
        //echo ("mssql database =".$mssqldatabasehidden." <br>");
        //echo ("mssql storage =".$mssqlstoragehidden." <br>");
        //echo ("mssqltotalcost =".$mssqltotalcosthidden." <br>");
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
        linux();
    </script>   
    <?
    if($_POST['mysqldatabasehidden'] =="")
    {   $mysqldatabasehidden = "0 No.";

        $mysqldatabasecost="0.00 INR";
    }
    else
    {
        $mysqldatabasehidden = $_POST['mysqldatabasehidden']." No";
        $mysqldatabasecost="0.00 INR";
        //echo ("mysqldatabse =".$mysqldatabasehidden." <br>");

    }

}
```

If windows selected than its call function name "windows" and same for "linux" when its in Else condition.

Here is my two functions

**JQ Functions**

```
<script>
    function windows()
    {
        alert();
        $("#divmssqldb").removeClass("divhide").addClass("divshow");
        $("#divmssqlstor").removeClass("divhide").addClass("divshow");
        $("#divmssqlprice").removeClass("divhide").addClass("divshow");
        $("#divmysql").addClass("divhide");
    }

    function linux()
    {
        alert();
        $("#divmssqldb").removeClass("divshow").addClass("divhide");
        $("#divmssqlstor").removeClass("divshow").addClass("divhide");
        $("#divmssqlprice").removeClass("divshow").addClass("divhide");
        $("#divmysql").removeClass("divhide").addClass("divshow");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where are you adding if condition? in view file?

Comment: @kumar_v Yes in View file

Comment: what is the error message you are getting? please check error console

Comment: @kumar_v there is no error message in console. In short I want to do that is, if we are in if condition. some jquery code comes in action (alert work but jquery not) and if in else condition other some jquery code should work, no meter if we write that code in function or not

Comment: add all the above code inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @kumar_v I try that but its ignore if-else and execute if condition's function

Comment: @kumar_v Done, Thanks buddy. this time document.ready work :)
thanks for help me out. +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `script` which is `written` in your `PHP code` and call your `functions` after there `definitions and declarations` like,

```
<script>
    function windows(){
        alert('windows');
        ....
    }

    function linux(){
        alert('linux');
        ....
    }
    $(function(){// add document ready function 
      <?php  if($osoption == "windows")  {  ?> windows(); <?php } ?>
      <?php  if($osoption == "linux")  {  ?> linux(); <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @ShivamPandya are you getting alert msg alteast?

Comment: Yes, but only when I wrote it in if-else condition with <script> tag.
?>
      <script>
       alert();
      </script>
     <?